# $(document).ready(function() with Meteor JS templates

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a template I've deeply integrated with Meteor. It uses a scripts.js file that runs a bunch of commands after $(document).ready and $(window).load.

I put scripts.js inside of client/compatibility, and it works only if I do a hard refresh of the template. Otherwise, the template doesn't render and the functions don't execute.

Specifically, this code:

```
    // Append .background-image-holder <img>'s as CSS backgrounds

$('.background-image-holder').each(function() {
    var imgSrc = $(this).children('img').attr('src');
    $(this).css('background', 'url("' + imgSrc + '")');
    $(this).children('img').hide();
    $(this).css('background-position', 'initial');
});
```

Much appreciated if you know how I should take it from here.

Comment: Why are you putting this script in `compatibility` directory?

Comment: where should I be putting it?

Comment: I was told to put all external js files in the compatibility dictionary.

Comment: I think that "external" here means "3rd party" so it only reffers to code you cannot edit easily (e.g. minified libraries).

Comment: what are you recommendations to integrating the scripts.js file?

Comment: https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/creating-an-app

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a function to fire off when the DOM is loaded *and* all images, use this: (be forewarned, this is in ES6)

```
let imgCount;
let imgTally = 0;

Template.myTemplate.onRendered(function () {
  this.autorun(() => {
    if (this.subscriptionsReady()) {
      Tracker.afterFlush(() => {
        imgCount = this.$('img').length;
      });
    }
  });
});

Template.myTemplate.events({
  'load img': function (event, template) {
    if (++imgTally >= imgCount) {
      (template.view.template.imagesLoaded.bind(template))();
    }
  }
});
```

Then you just need to declare `imagesLoaded` which will get fired off when all images are done.

```
Template.myTemplate.imagesLoaded = function () {
  // do something
};
```

Answer (score 4):

Place this stuff in the onRendered function of the template.

```
Template.<name>.onRendered(function(){
//do your jquery business here!
});
```

[For more info check the docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_onRendered)

Comment: Unfortunately, this only works when the template is being rendered. It doesn't account for images not loaded, when the template isn't being re-rendered, etc.